# Let $G$ be a group, $|G|=n$. Suppose $\forall d\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d\mid n$, there are at most $d$ elements s.t. $x^d=1$. Prove $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group, $|G|=n$. Suppose  $\forall d\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d\mid n$, there are at most $d$ elements such that $x^d=1$. Prove $G$ is cyclic.

I saw these posts:

- [If a finite group $G$ of order $n$ has at most one subgroup of each order $d\mid n$, then $G$ is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736563/if-a-finite-group-g-of-order-n-has-at-most-one-subgroup-of-each-order-d-mid?rq=1)
- [How do I show that a finite group $G$ of order $n$ is cyclic if there is at most one subgroup of order $d$ for each $d\mid n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814952/how-do-i-show-that-a-finite-group-g-of-order-n-is-cyclic-if-there-is-at-most?rq=1)

I am not sure these questions' posts have the same meaning as my own question.

**My attempt:**

My approach is to show $G$ has at most one subgroup of each of each order $d\mid n$.

Using cauchy theorem there is a **cyclic** subgroup in order $p$ for each $p\mid n$ such that $p$ is a prime number.

Let $H<G,|H|=p$, $\forall h\in H$ exists $\space O(h)=p$ (Lagrange's Theorem).

Combining this and the given fact that there are at most $p$ elements $\implies H$ is the unique subgroup with order $p$.

My problem is, how do I deal with non-primary order subgroup?

Any help (and another approach) is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ isn't cyclic. Let $x\in G$.  Then $d=| x|\lt n$.  By Euler's formula,  $$n=\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)\gt\sum_{d\mid n,d\ne n}\varphi (d)=| G|.$$

The reason we can use Euler's formula here is that by hypothesis there's at most one cyclic subgroup of each order dividing $n$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $d=\mid x\mid\lt n$? what is $|x|$? thanks

Comment: Since $G$ isn't cyclic,  the order of any element is less than $n$.  $\mid x\mid$ is the order of $x$.